# Unable to debug SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure from SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to debug a stored proc on a SQL Server 2008 server from my development workstation.

The server is running SQL Server 2008 (10.0.2531.0) and I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on my workstation (10.50.1600.1).

I'm 99% certain that this combination has worked in the past, but something has changed recently so that it no longer works.  I know I've been able to debug against this server in the past.

When I hit the "Debug" button in SQL Management Studio, the proc just runs.  Previously, it would step into the proc and stop on the first line.  Even if I set a breakpoint in the proc the debugger never stops.

If I remote desktop to the SQL server I am able to debug the proc using SQL Management Studio on the server.

What configuration settings and/or security rights should I look at to troubleshoot this?

Is there any sort of debugger log that I could view to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Windows login you used with local Management Studio also is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role on remote instance of SQL Server

Comment: Yes, my account is a member of the sysadmin role.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, if a user under which account sql server is running already have admin privileges - LocalSystem, for example? Can you perform debugging locally @ sql server?

Comment: The SQL Server is running as "Network Service".  I am able to debug successfully on the SQL server if I use Remote Desktop to log in with the same account that I'm logged into on my local desktop.